# compile similar files in a directory with lualatex - without loading fonts each time

Tags: luatex, latexmk

I have a number of `tex` files (>20) to compile. I use `lualatex` and observe that lualatex each time starts and loads the same fonts etc. (all the `tex` files have the same preamble).

Is there a way to have all the files compiled in one go without restarting lualatex each time? I understand that the problem could be solved with some bash level programming, but this would incur the initialization each time ([for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233678/using-latexmk-with-multiple-tex-files-in-the-directory))

I would appreciate an example which can be adapted to my problem. Eventually, I have to integrate this in a [Shake process](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake)...

Comment: essentially, no you can not preload the fonts

Comment: Thank you for the simple direct answer. Any other idea how to reduce the repeated invocation? I am reading a paper by robertson on loading fonts in latex; perhaps my fonts are not optimal. Suggestions for good and uptodate information appreciated!

Comment: I added a timer and see that it takes 9 .. 10 seconds to process a tex file by lualatex, The files are fairly small (few lines to 2 pages), thus most of the time is in likely in setup and processing the preamble.